# aexmachina/factory-girl (Node) cannot associate factory with non persisted model

Tags: sequelize.js, factory-bot

I'm attempting to associate a factory model with a non perisisted one but am getting the error:

```
     TypeError: model.get is not a function
      at SequelizeAdapter.get (node_modules/src/adapters/DefaultAdapter.js:13:18)
      at AssocAttrs.get [as getAttribute] (node_modules/src/generators/Generator.js:15:46)
      at AssocAttrs.getAttribute (node_modules/src/generators/AssocAttrs.js:7:23)
      at tryCatch (node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
      at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
      at Generator.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next] (node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
      at step (node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:30)
      at /Users/daniel.pan/Documents/projects/BudgetApp/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:28:13
```

This is the factory that I have:

```
import models from '../../models'
import faker from 'faker/locale/en'

export default factory.define('Expense', models.Expense, {
  id: factory.seq('id'),
  value: faker.finance.amount(0, 200),
  note: faker.lorem.sentence(),
  categoryId: factory.assocAttrs('Category', 'id'),
  userId: factory.assocAttrs('User', 'id')
})
```

I'm trying to associate "Expense" with "Category" and "User".
I can just use "assoc" and it works but this is for persisted models which I do not want. The docs say to use "assocAttrs" for to embed models that are not persisted howoever i always get the type error. I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty late, but change the line of code as follows for `categoryId` from:

```
categoryId: factory.assocAttrs('Category', 'id'),
```

To:

```
categoryId: factory.assocAttrs('Category'),
```

Which should result in a JSON output when you invoke:

```
factory.build('Expense').then(x => console.log(x)).
```

You will notice that your `categoryId` property will contain a JSON object, which will contain properties initialized to however you defined them. That is `Expense.category = {propA: 'whatever you've defined', probB: 'etc...', categoryId: '123-213-123'}`

To ensure that the `Expense.categoryId` property is set to only the `categoryId` in the above JSON object, you will need to change the line of code I mention above to:

```
categoryId: factory.assocAttrs('Category')().then(y => y.categoryId)
```